# Getting unexpected end of file error while using getopts in Shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Here is the following code:

```
compact()        { echo "compact alarms" }

node() { echo "node alarms" }

severity() { echo "Severity alarms" }

csv() { echo "CSV generator" }

table() { echo "tabular data" }

help() { echo "help" }

exit() { echo "exit" }

while getopts ":c :n :s :x :t :h :e" opt; do
  case $opt in
            c) compact
                ;;
            n) node
                ;;
            s) severity
                ;;
            x) csv
                ;;
            t) table
                ;;
            h) help
                ;;
            e) exit
                ;;
            *)
                echo "Error wrong Syntax,Opening help" && help
                ;;
        esac
done
```

when I am executing **sh test.sh -t newfile** I am getting Syntax error 
test.sh: line 36: syntax error: unexpected end of file
Can someone please tell me why it is displaying unexpected end of file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a wrong syntax for the functions, to use *oneliners* try this instead:

```
help() { echo "help";}

exit() { echo "exit";}
```

**Explanation**

From `bash` *man* page:

> **Shell Function Definitions**
>
> A shell function is an object that is called like a simple command and
>   executes a compound command with a new  set  of  positional 
>   parameters.   Shell  functions  are declared as follows:
>
> ```
>    [ function ] name () compound-command [redirection]
> ```

---

> **Compound Commands**
>
> `{ list; }` list  is  simply executed in the current shell environment.  list **must be terminated** with a **newline** or
>   **semicolon**.  This is known as a group command.